# How to put flag Yes/No if the value changes in a column for the same Order ID

Tags: sql, oracle, lag

I am trying to select Orders (Customers) that changed tariff over the time. I have these columns:

| customer_account_id | VERSION_CHANGE_NUMBER | VERSION_CHANGE_DATE | TARIFF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1230000000 | 1 | 01-01-2018 | day24 tariff |
| 1230000000 | 2 | 11-01-2018 | day24 tariff |
| 1230000000 | 3 | 15-02-2018 | day12 tariff |

I need to put flag "Y" on the right hand site in case tariff changes, in this case from "**day24 tariff**" into "**day12 tariff**".

Then I need to aggregate it by **customer_account_id** to get information which Customers changed the tariff, and when.

I tried with LAG function, but cannot get right answer.

Can you help me out?

Thanks,
Pawel

Comment: Your account numbers are different, so are you looking at at any tariff change regardless of account - just based on version change number, or date? What should the first row (earliest change umber/date) show - null or Yes or No?

Comment: I have just noticed that.. and corrected. In my example Order IDs are the same. The reason for this is because I am using the History Table, where one Order ID is saved multiple times if changes. The change_version_number is added as well as the date.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the previous tariff for an account with:

```
lag(tariff) over (partition by customer_account_id order by version_change_number)
```

You can order by either `version_change_number` or `version_change_date` if they are consistent; if not you'll need to pick which to use.

Then you can use that in a case expression, including handling for the lag being null (for the first version/date for each account):

```
select customer_account_id, version_change_number, version_change_date, tariff,
  case
    when lag(tariff) over (partition by customer_account_id order by version_change_number) is null
      or lag(tariff) over (partition by customer_account_id order by version_change_number) != tariff then 'Yes'
    else 'No'
  end as flag
from orders
```

or to avoid repeating the lag put that in a CTE or inline view:

```
select customer_account_id, version_change_number, version_change_date, tariff,
  case
    when lag_tariff is null or lag_tariff != tariff then 'Yes'
    else 'No'
  end as flag
from (
  select customer_account_id, version_change_number, version_change_date, tariff,
    lag(tariff) over (partition by customer_account_id order by version_change_number) as lag_tariff
  from orders
)
```

| CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_ID | VERSION_CHANGE_NUMBER | VERSION_CHANGE_DATE | TARIFF | FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1230000000 | 1 | 01-JAN-18 | day24 tariff | Yes |
| 1230000000 | 2 | 11-JAN-18 | day24 tariff | No |
| 1230000000 | 3 | 15-FEB-18 | day12 tariff | Yes |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=41cf9b5e7e52576b5d9de654ac7e1b64)

Comment: Thanks for the query. Just checked, in my example it only assigns flag Yes to orders with version_change_number = 1. It does not recognize changes.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - you can see it sets it to Yes for change number 3 above. If you have data that isn't doing that then we'd need to see it to see why (or why it actually shouldn't).